# Ajax doesn't work on mobile unless using www. prefix

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, mobile, iis-6

I have a web page that uses Ajax and it works great on the desktop using domain.com or [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com).
It also works great on mobile, as long as I use the [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com) URL.

When accessing the naked domain from mobile everything works except the "ajax button". I added a alert() in the onclick event and it works, but won't go on to call the Ajax function (doesn't even get to the function - I added an alert() in there, too, but it never fires).

I am using IIS6 and have multiple identities defined for the website (for domain.com as well as [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)). They both work, but the function that calls Ajax only works (on mobile) if the www is in front.

I am retrieving a local file with the Ajax call.

I have found lots of solutions to remap naked to www, but I don't seem to have any URL rewrite/redirect functionality, I don't have a web.config file, etc. being on IIS6.

I would like to support either URL being entered into a browser.

When using mobile, the button just seems "dead" when using the naked domain.

Here's the code:

```
    <!-- mainpage -->
<button onclick="showRegistrationForm();"><b>Register</b></button>

<!-- in scripts.js) -->

function showRegistrationForm()    {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'Server.asp?a=newform', true);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(this.status == 200){
           document.getElementById('regform').innerHTML=this.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('errmsg').innerHTML="Status " + this.status;
        }
    }
    xhr.onerror = function(){ console.log('Request Error...');}
    xhr.send()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include relevant parts of your code.    As posted, there's little anyone can help with aside for speculating which won't help much.

Comment: I sense a CORS error - probably because your AJAX calls are probably hardcoded to use the www. host - but without code, that's just a feeling

Comment: Edit your post! Don't put code in comments.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't know I could. I'll Try that.

Comment: I added the code to my post. I think if I switch from .html to .asp I can do Response.Redirect if not www

Comment: I ended up used a front-end asp page and re-directed as necessary. Thanks for the help.